# Should my ViewModel have an ObservableCollection of Views or ViewModels?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, observablecollection, itemscontrol

I'm trying to understand the basic MVVM design approach when using **ItemsControl** by binding it via **DataTemplates** to **ObservableCollections** on the ViewModel.

I've seen examples that bind to ObservableCollections of **strings**, **Views**, and **ViewModels**.

Binding to strings seems to be only for **demos**, it is the binding to "**ViewModels that contain collections of Views that contain collections of ViewModels**" that the power of WPF seems to really come out.

**For those of use proficient in the MVVM pattern, what is your standard approach to binding ItemsControl, ListView, ListBox to collections in a ViewModel?** I'm looking for advice from experience like this:

- always use ObservableCollection<...> and never List<...> because...
- something better than ItemsControl to display a collection is...
- in order to get filtering to work in your ViewModel instead of code-behind, use...
- use collections of Views when ... and collections of ViewModels when...
- 90% of the time I create an ItemsControl and bind it to an ObservableCollection of Views which have their own ViewModels...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would use an ObservableCollection of ViewModels for the following reasons:

- ObservableCollection already has events available for signaling when it has been modified (e.g. when items are added/removed from the collection).
- We're at the ViewModel 'layer' so it provides cleaner separation to have a ViewModel contain a collection of ViewModels rather than Views
- If it is necessary to modify or get data from items within the collection you can more easily modify/access that data if the items are ViewModels (if they're views you'll frequently be casting the View's DataContext or accessing its UI elements).

Comment: +1, this is definitely the way to go. your viewmodel has collections of viewmodels and your view's resource collection has datatemplates for each of those viewmodels.

Answer (score 1):

I like using an ObservableCollection of ViewModels. The view that binds to the collection can define a DataTemplate that gives the ViewModel its look. This leads to less coupling among the components.

Comment: If you have an ObservableCollection of ViewModels (instead of Views), then what is the difference between having that XAML in your DataTemplate and having that XAML the .xaml file of a View?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same question, but replace the "view" with "model". :)

I have a MODEL with a collection of other models.
I want my viewmodel to have an observable collection of other viewmodels, but once I instantiate it like that - the connection between the model collection content is lost.
Do I now need to start wiring all the events from the viewmodels observable collection back to the models collection?

Comment: Yes, event's is the best way to do it. Consider using the weak event pattern for safety.